# Div Not Fitting to Content

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my div.  I'm floating an image to the right and I've got my text beside it.  I'm trying to make a `linear-gradient` div, however, the `div` is filling the entire page.

So how do I make my `div` fit my contents only?

I've tried the `inline-block` way and it just effective clears my text to below the image.

The issue:

[image]

---

Code:

```css
.Popcorn {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -45px;
}
.Software {
  padding: 4px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #277FD8 0%, #ffffff 30%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="/img/popcorn_edited.png" class="Popcorn" />
<div class="Software">
  <h3>The Software You Want!</h3>
  <br>
  <p>Android is the World's leading mobile and tablet operating system. This means no learning curves for Android users. The media box is powered by Android which allows you to download applications and share it with all your Android devices or vice versa.
    You can download from millions of apps, games, books, movies and more on the Google Play store.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The div is actually behaves as you like, it have the size of the content. https://jsfiddle.net/c8k5t4mg/

Comment: You're right, that jsfiddle works fine, but in my code it's not supposed to fit the image.  It's not wrapped around it.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries.  I tend to describe stuff awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a width to your div with gradient with `calc()` function, if you know the popcorn image has a fixed width :

```
.Software {
  padding: 4px;
  width: calc(100% - 350px);
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #277FD8 0%, #ffffff 30%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/b783ppup/1/)

Comment: Good solution if OP can't change the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Put the image *into* the DIV

2.) Assign `overflow: auto;` to the container to also cover the floated image.

```
<div class="Software">
  <img src="/img/popcorn_edited.png" class="Popcorn"/>
  <h3>The Software You Want!</h3>
    <p>Android is the World's leading mobile and tablet operating system. This means no learning curves for Android users. The media box is powered by Android which allows you to download applications and share it with all your Android devices or vice versa. You can download from millions of apps, games, books, movies and more on the Google Play store.</p>
</div>

.Popcorn {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -45px;
}
.Software {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #277FD8 0%, #ffffff 30%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can easily solve this with `flexbox`,  plus remove `min-width:100%` from `.Software`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.wrap {
  display: flex
}
.Software {
  padding: 4px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #277FD8 0%, #ffffff 30%, #ffffff 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="Software">
    <h3>The Software You Want!</h3>
    <br>
    <p>Android is the World's leading mobile and tablet operating system. This means no learning curves for Android users. The media box is powered by Android which allows you to download applications and share it with all your Android devices or vice versa.
      You can download from millions of apps, games, books, movies and more on the Google Play store.</p>
  </div>
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" class="Popcorn" />
</div>
```

Comment: Mmmm, there are a fashion right now to convert all layouts to flexbox. I love flexbox but this seems exaggerated.  However it works, my upvote.

Comment: just a way to simplify the code ( I always try to simplify the code as possible), and it is a way to me too to keep learning more and more about flexbox, see my mistakes and so on. I would thank your upvote, but I didn't see it yet ;)